# picture box image does not change in C#

Tags: c#

I want to change picture's box image when my board(a USB  module) is joined or disjoined to computer. But I think my thread will execute just one time. And picture box's image won't change.

my code:

```
bool boardjoined = false;
void BoardConnecion()
{
    foreach (var item in SerialPort.GetPortNames())
    {
        if (item == "COM3")
        {
            boardjoined = true;
            DisplayImage(_pic_usb, "on.png");
        }
        else
        {
            boardjoined = false;
            DisplayImage(_pic_usb, "off.png");
        }

    }
}

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _pic_usb.Image = Bitmap.FromFile(Application.StartupPath + @"\off.png");

    new Thread(new ThreadStart(BoardConnecion)).Start();

}

private void DisplayImage(PictureBox pic, string picName)
{
    pic.Invoke(new EventHandler(delegate
    {
        pic.Image = Bitmap.FromFile(Application.StartupPath +@"\" + picName);
    }));
}
```

Comment: try to add a cycle in `BoardConnecion` with some `Delay` - 100ms. So the thread will check every 100ms if a board is connected

Comment: but i want to thread will check every moment.not by timer.my program must listen to port every moment and transfer information

Comment: that would be bad, without delay, its gonna cause 100% load on processor. Delay of 100ms or 50ms is not a big deal. You are already waiting for driver initialization(it takes some time from board connection till COM3 is creted or no?)Also itwould be a good idea to run `DisplayImage` only when the state is changed

Comment: Take a look at questions 12 and 15 here : http://msmvps.com/blogs/coad/archive/2005/03/23/39466.aspx#usb. That might help.

Comment: i agree with @Uriel_SVK, unnecessary looping would be a bad practice, you can hook onto `SerialPort.DataReceived Event` for checking if there is a device or not

Answer (score 1):

You can do a never ending loop in the BoardConnection.

```
    void BoardConnecion()
    {
        while(true)
        {
            foreach (var item in SerialPort.GetPortNames())
            {
                if (item == "COM3")
                {
                    boardjoined = true;
                    DisplayImage(_pic_usb, "on.png");
                }
                else
                {
                    boardjoined = false;
                    DisplayImage(_pic_usb, "off.png");
                }

            }
            Thread.Sleep(500);
        }
    }
```

You should proabably add a safety switch to get out of the loop to. =)

Comment: it will be good to add some delay there, or it can get nasty - 100% processor load and so

Answer (score 0):

you can use below mentioned code

```
private System.Timers.Timer timerClock = new System.Timers.Timer();    
timerClock.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimer);
timerClock.Interval = 1000;
timerClock.Enabled = true;

public void OnTimer( Object source, ElapsedEventArgs e )
{
    foreach (var item in SerialPort.GetPortNames())
        {
            if (item == "COM3")
            {
                boardjoined = true;
                DisplayImage(_pic_usb, "on.png");
            }
            else
            {
                boardjoined = false;
                DisplayImage(_pic_usb, "off.png");
            }

        } 
}
```